# configuring multiple modules in Zendframework

Tags: zend-framework

I want to setup a multiple module in zendframework but it's not working in index file after require_once and is not going into the application.ini file.
Here is my index.php code.

```
 <?php
defined('BASE_PATH')
|| define('BASE_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));

defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', BASE_PATH . '/application');


defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'):   'production'));

set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array( 
realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
APPLICATION_PATH,
APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules',
get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

$application = new Zend_Application(
APPLICATION_ENV,
APPLICATION_PATH .'/configs/application.ini'
);
print_r(APPLICATION_PATH);die;   


$application->Bootstrap()->run();

 ?>
```

Here is my application.ini file code.

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"


resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = ""
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"


resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.layout.layoutpath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove The `die;` after `print_r(APPLICATION_PATH);`  or remove that whole line you don't need it..

Comment: but that line was added for just to check if it prints the application path or not, if I remove that line still it's not working.